# Redirect in POST method in Iris Framework

Tags: go, go-iris

I'm trying to redirect from the login page to the home page in the POST method, but the form doesn't redirect to any page after clicking on the submit button.

I'm using the MVC structure of Iris Framework and the `Ctx.Redirect` method to redirect to the desired page, but it's not working.

```
// login_controllers.go
package controllers

import (
    "github.com/kataras/iris/mvc"
    "github.com/kataras/iris"
    "fmt"
)

type LoginFormData struct {
    Email string
    Password string
}


type LoginController struct {
    mvc.C
}

func (c *LoginController) Get() mvc.Result {
    return mvc.View{
        Name: "login.html",
    }
}

func (c *LoginController) Post() {
    userLoginData := LoginFormData{}
    err := c.Ctx.ReadForm(&userLoginData)
    if err != nil {
        c.Ctx.StatusCode(iris.StatusInternalServerError)
        c.Ctx.WriteString(err.Error())
    }

    if userLoginData.Email == "teste@teste.com" && userLoginData.Password == "123" {
        c.Ctx.Redirect("/", iris.StatusSeeOther)

        fmt.Printf("UserInner: %#v", userLoginData)
        c.Ctx.Writef("UserInner: %#v", userLoginData)
    }
}
```

The form HTML code is:

```
<form class="m-login__form m-form" action="/login" method="post">
    <div class="form-group m-form__group">
        <input class="form-control m-input" type="text" placeholder="Email" name="Email" autocomplete="off">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group m-form__group">
        <input class="form-control m-input m-login__form-input--last" type="password" placeholder="Password" name="Password">
    </div>
    <div class="row m-login__form-sub">
        <div class="col m--align-left">
            <label class="m-checkbox m-checkbox--focus">
            <input type="checkbox" name="remember">
                Remember me
            <span></span>
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="col m--align-right">
            <a href="javascript:;" id="m_login_forget_password" class="m-link">
            Forgotten password ?
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="m-login__form-action">
        <button id="m_login_signin_submit" class="btn btn-focus m-btn m-btn--pill m-btn--custom m-btn--air">
        Login
        </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Isn't possible to redirect in a POST method in Iris Framework/Go?

Comment: Writing after redirect, or even before, makes little sense. Try removing the `...Writef...` line and see what happens.

Comment: @mkopriva I just tried that and it's still not working :/

Comment: And do you at least see the printf output in the console?

Comment: Yes, it shows: `UserInner: controllers.LoginFormData{Email:"teste@teste.com", Password:"123"}`

Answer (score 1):

As @mkopriva said you have to call .Redirect and return from the function body, Redirect should be the last call because it sends the status code and a header location back to the client, you don't have to write anything else, browser/client will redirect and write the content of the redirect path.

Although `iris.StatusSeeOther` (http status code: 303) works on the mvc examples the iris repository has, you may want to try other statuses and check if that works (clear your browser's cache on each try for any case), for example `iris.StatusTemporaryRedirect` (http status code: 307) or search on google for the correct redirect status code that suits your needs better.

Please take a look at the https://github.com/kataras/iris/tree/master/_examples as well.

Comment: Probably you should disclose yourself as the author, as required by site rules ;)

Comment: I found the problem, it was being caused by my Javascript code that was dynamically adding some classes to the button to handle a "loading effect" when submitting the form. I don't know exactly why, but for some reason it wasn't allowing the page to redirect.